# User management system in CakePHP 2.x behaves strange

Tags: cakephp, authentication, authorization

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6. In one project, I have to implement `User Management System` for multiple kind of users(`Users, Admins, etc.`). For now, I only concerned about `Admin Panel(only 1 Admin for now)` and `User Panel`. I want that `Admin` can access all areas(including `User Panel`'s all pages), and `Users` will have to `login` to access certain areas(pages), as usual.

I created 2 `controllers` for `Admin Panel` and `User Panel`, instead of having different `plugins` for different `user panels`. Here is the full project's code :

```
AppController.php :

public $components=array('Session','RequestHandler','Auth');
public function isAuthorized($user){
    if(isset($user['role']) && $user['role']==='admin')
        return true;
    return false;
}

UsersController.php :

public function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect=array('action'=>'editProfile');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect=array('action'=>'index');
    $this->Auth->authenticate=array('Form'=>array('scope'=>array('User.role'=>"user"),'userModel'=>'User','fields'=>array('username','password')));
    $this->Auth->unauthorizedRedirect=array('action'=>'login');
    $this->Auth->loginAction=array('action'=>'login');
    $this->Auth->deny('editCv','logout');
    $this->layout='user_layout';
}
public function login(){
    if($this->request->is('post'))
        if($this->Auth->login()){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Welcome '.$this->User->field('name',array('User.id'=>$this->Auth->user('id'))));
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid username or password, please try again');
            $this->set('title_for_layout','Error - Login');
        }
}
public function logout(){
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}

AdminsController.php

public function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect=array('action'=>'myJobs');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect=array('action'=>'index');
    $this->Auth->authenticate=array('Form'=>array('scope'=>array('User.role'=>"admin"),'userModel'=>'User','fields'=>array('username','password')));
    $this->Auth->authError='Did you really think you are allowed to see that ?';
    $this->Auth->unauthorizedRedirect=array('action'=>'index');
    $this->Auth->loginAction=array('action'=>'index');
    $this->Auth->deny('myUsers','deleteUser','logout');
    $this->layout='admin_layout';
}
public function index(){
    if($this->request->is('post'))
        if($this->Auth->login()){
            $this->Session->setFlash("<p style='margin-left:20px;color:#366;'><strong>Welcome Admin, You have successfully entered to your Admin Panel!</strong></p>");
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid username or password, please try again');
            $this->set('title_for_layout','Error - Login');
        }
    else
        $this->set('title_for_layout','Admin');
    $this->layout=false;
}
public function logout(){
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

Here, I am implementing `login` in both panels individually, because I have 2 different `login pages` for both panels. That's why I configured `AuthComponent` in 2 panels individually.

Now, what's happening is, in the `User panel(UsersController)`, a user cant access any page without logging in, but I want that my users will see the `index` page without login.

And, when I login from `Admin panel`(AdminsController), it gets me to the `User panel(UsersController)`'s `login` page, saying that I successfully entered to my Admin panel, but I still cant access admin panel.

I tried `$this->Auth->authorize('Controller')`, but same result. I thought `allow()` or `deny()` function will be enough here, but don't know what's going on, what is my fault.

Before I manually implemented `login/logout` system using `Session`, and it was working fine. Then I thought to use `AuthComponent`, but its driving me crazy.

Can anyone help me, please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first try to follow [coding standards](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html) and best practises like not mixing inline css with html, etc. It will make it far easier to have a look at your code and understand it.

Going now to your problems. `AuthenticationComponent` assumes everything is denied unless it is passed in `Auth::allow()` first. So `Auth::deny()` is just making your code deny your already denied methods and not allow the rest. You could say `Auth::allow('*')` first and then deny something but I consider it better to explicitly allow actions than to explicitly deny them (and then forget to deny a new one and expose it to the world).

When you do `$this->redirect` precede it with a return statement. This way you stop the execution of your code at that point, else it might continue to paths you didn't expect. Since your problem seems to be a wrong redirect, instead of redirecting to `$this->Auth->redirect()` try `$this->redirect(array('controller => 'admin', 'action' => 'index'));`.

Finally what is the purpose of `AppController::isAuthorized()`? Is it called from some place?

Comment: Thanks, looks like it'll solve my problem. Actually, I tried using allow() too, but same result. And, isAuthorized() is not used anywhere, I just kept it here according to the example in the CakePHP documentation. Well, I'll try again removing it. @user221931

Comment: And, should I use this : $this->Auth->authorize('Controller') ?

Comment: Working better, but still behaves strange. I tying to login from 'Admin' panel & 'User' panel in the same browser, same tab, one-by-one. Is that a problem ? Is there any 'cookie' issue ? @user221931

Comment: And, I am following the coding standard perfectly. @user221931

Comment: @Musabbir Ahmed you clearly don't, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html just run phpcs with the CakePHP rule set and you'll see.

Comment: Everytime you login you set a cookie (check your response in the browser). If you login from one tab and then login again from another you just delete your cookie and setup another. What you need is to check if the user is logged in AND has the necessary privilege for each controller method. Not two login pages.